# Dynamic select menus not working with added fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails nested form with the child fields that contain dynamic select menus:
--category (filter menu)
--products

I can get a single fieldset to work, but I have hack the products menu (by using a "backup" collection_select in main form that is DOM ready) because I couldn't get the .html() to load the select data on a dynamic field.  I'm using the revised Railscast #88 as the template code.

The real issue is that only the first select menu combo work -- when I select the category menu in additional fieldsets, all menus fail.  I tried adding a (this) method, but could get it to work.

Any insights greatly appreciated!

Relevent js.coffee:

```
products = $('.products-backup').html()
$('form').on 'change', '.category', (event) ->
category = $('.category :selected').text()
escaped_category = category.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_category}']").html()
if options
    $('.products').html(options)
else
    $('.products').empty()
```

Relevent rails html.erb partial - note, I assigned :class names to each select menu:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="field">
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Select' }, 
{ :class => "category" } %> 
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.order(:name), :products, 
:name, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Select' }, { :class => "products" } %>
</div>
#...more fields
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeff, you my want something like this:

```
var $products_backup = $('#products_backup');
$('form').on('click', '.category', function() {
    var $category = $(this);
    if (!$category.is(":checked")) {
        return;
    }
    var escaped_category = $category.val().replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    var $options = $products_backup.find("optgroup[label='" + escaped_category + "']").find("option");
    //$('#products').empty().append('<option value="">Select an item</option>').append($options.clone()).val("");
    $category.closest('fieldset').find('.products').empty().append('<option value="">Select an item</option>').append($options.clone()).val("");
});
```

See :

- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zvNQf/) (original)
- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zvNQf/2/) (update)

As you will see I guessed that the `.category` elements might be radio buttons. If they are not, then the code will need to be adjusted to a greater or lesser extent.

Comment: code works greats...I needed to make a minor change to the radio menu format related to the rails model. One issue that remains is multiple sets of radio/selects in the same form.  So, when I change a category it changes all the products select because of same class name - any ideas for how link each radio with its corresponding product select?

Comment: @Jeff, on the basis that each set of related elements is contained within a fieldset, then try the edited last line of my code above - and corresponding updated fiddle.

Comment: perfect solution!  Thanks for your help, this saved me hours/days!